# Каким парсить документ из SharePoint Document Library?

Tags: c#, excel, list, sharepoint

Здравствуйте! такая стоит задач: Необходимо добавить документ Excel.xlsx в SharePoint Document Library, потом его парсить и вывести в List. Не могу понять именно процесс парсинга, если нужны будут только некоторые ячейки, как сделать выборку именно из них?

Думал использовать библиотеку SpreadsheetLight. У кого какие будут мысли по поводу задачи?

И еще, с Interop-оп не получится, так как на сервере нет Офиса.

Comment: Т.е. нужно создать произвольный список на базе файла Excel?

Comment: Да, лист на базе документа Excel, но что бы можно было после загрузки и открытия в листе, выбирать нужные данные из документа, допустим в текст бокс скопировать через баттон, ну а из данных нужно только выборка по ячейке - Person_Name.

Comment: Описание просто жесть. Либо опишите нормально "исходные данные, необходимые действия, конечный результат", либо просто никто не поймет вопрос. Может стоит нарисовать схематично, что Вы хотите.

Comment: Вот:
1. Есть документ Excel. Нужно его загрузить в document library, потом на его базе создать SharePoint List.
2. Парсить документ, что бы извлечь нужную информацию с ячеек.(Person Name - ключ)
На странице SharePoint list-а - создать поле, где мы указываем имя человека, и жмем на кнопку рядом, подтверждаем поиск. Находим человека с листа. Дальше действия уже не обязательны.
P.S. Вот этот документ нужно обновлять раз в год, поэтому когда добавляем уже новый, нужно что бы он перезаписал старый.

Comment: Пример как разпарсить xlsx http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600965/17974

Answer (score 3):

Вот хороший пример как это сделать с помощью Ajax(JQuery)

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var table = $("<table />");
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = $("<tr />");
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                            var cell = $("<td />");
                            cell.html(cells[j]);
                            row.append(cell);
                        }
                        table.append(row);
                    }
                    $("#dvCSV").html('');
                    $("#dvCSV").append(table);
                }
                reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
<hr />
<div id="dvCSV">
</div>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]