# экспорт данных из Excel через OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, недавно столкнулся с проблемой обработки больших Excel файлов (порядка 160 Мб, более 560000, более 26 столбцов). В общем, пытаюсь загрузить таблицу Excel в DataSet и обработать. Использую следующий код:

```
using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

    string sheetName = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtSheet.Rows)
        {
            // dr["TABLE_NAME"] = "Table";
            sheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            // Get all rows from the Sheet
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.TableName = sheetName;

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        outputDataExcel(string.Format("Ошибка заполнения таблицы. Error:{0}", ex.Message));
    }
}
```

На строчке `da.Fill(dt)` возникает ошибка: "Недостаточно системных ресурсов.", Хотя на машине еще свободно 9 Гб оперативной памяти, сам же процесс заполнения таблицы (`da.Fill(dt)`) съедает 2.3 Гб оперативной памяти.

Помогите решить проблему, пробовал экспортировать данные через `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, но он работает очень медленно из-за обращения к Excel ячейкам.

**Обновление**

Попробовал сделать так:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Лист1$]", connection);

    connection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    try
    {
        dataTable.Load(reader);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Получил ту же ошибку в строке

```
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Нормальный код:

Comment: Вы грузите сразу все таблицы в `DataSet`. Грузите и обрабатывайте их по одной. Или даже первая не грузится?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov
Там всего одна таблица, и как я понимаю 
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
выбирает по одной таблице.

Comment: Да, но ведь в цикле они добавляются в датасет.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov
и? Падает на первой таблице.

Comment: Значит не нужно использовать `DataTable` и `DataAdapter`. Читать в цикле с помощью `DataReader`. Тем более, что метод `Fill` работает медленно, а вам нужна скорость.

Comment: Я бы импортировал бы через DeflateStream + XmlReader

Comment: @nick_n_a Код в студию.)

Comment: Наверное не экспорт, а "импорт данных из excel"

Comment: @nick_n_a, я экспортирую данные из таблицы Excel, посмотрите значение слов экспорт и импотр.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам спросил, сам отвечу. Ошибка возникает из-за малого адресного пространства (количества оперативной памяти) выделяемого для процесса 32-ой системой (кому интересно [ссылка](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mark_russinovich/2008/11/17/windows-3/)!). Проект собирался в visual studio, а у неё есть такая опция (Debug->Диспетчер конфигурации), где можно собирать проект под 32-х или 64-ех разрядную систему(по умолчанию Any CPU). В общем, собрал проект под 64-х разрядную систему и ошибка исчезла. P.S. Есть еще одна тонкость - в проекте используется           `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` при работе с COM объектами(могу ошибаться), если вы хотите собрать проект под 64-х разрядную платформу то у вас должен стоять 64-х разрядный Microsoft Office, т.к. именно он в основном устанавливает драйвер `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

Comment: Подскажите, это решение вопроса или его дополнение?

Answer (score 0):

Самописный код потокового импорта xslx. Ипортирует excel как текст. Не требует нестандартных библиотек. Поддерживает NET 2.0.  sheet_no=1 поставить.  Страницы начинаются с 1.

```
    public static List<string[]> import_xlsx(Stream file, int sheet_no)    {
        //FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        //XmlDocument sharedString = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument page = new XmlDocument();
        List<string> sharedString = new List<string>();
        List<string> colums = new List<string>();
        List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
        string Query = "xl/worksheets/sheet"+ sheet_no + ".xml";
        int ready = 0;
        while (ready < 2)   {
            byte[] head = new byte[30];  file.Read(head, 0, 30);  if (head[0] != 'P') break;  //zip-header
            int i =(head[27] + head[29]) * 256 + head[28]; //  extra len
            long paked = head[18] + ((head[19] + (head[20] + head[21] * 256) * 256) * 256);
            byte[] nam = new byte[255];
            file.Read(nam, 0, head[26]);                
            if (i!=0) file.Seek(i, SeekOrigin.Current);                
            String aname = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(nam, 0, head[26]);
            if ((aname == "xl/sharedStrings.xml") || (aname == Query) || (paked == 0)){
                long lastpos = file.Position;
                System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream deflate = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(file, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress);                    
                if (aname == "xl/sharedStrings.xml") {
                    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                    xml.Load(deflate);
                    foreach (XmlNode node in xml.SelectNodes("/*/*/*"))
                        sharedString.Add(node.InnerText);
                    ready++;
                } else if (aname == Query) { page.Load(deflate); ready++; };
                file.Position = lastpos + paked;                    
            }  else file.Seek(paked, SeekOrigin.Current); 
        };
        int line = 1;
        foreach (XmlNode n in page.SelectNodes("/*/*/*"))
        {  /*nodes*/
            if (n.LocalName == "row")                
                foreach (XmlNode nn in n.ChildNodes)
                {
                    string xpos = nn.Attributes["r"].Value;
                    int line2 = 0;     int ss = -1;           int v = -1;
                    int.TryParse(xpos.Substring(1), out line2);
                    if (line2 != line){ data.Add(colums.ToArray()); /*ИМПОРТ ТУТ*/   colums.Clear();   line = line2; }
                    if (nn.FirstChild != null) int.TryParse(nn.FirstChild.InnerText, out v);
                    colums.Add((nn.Attributes["t"] == null) ? ((nn.FirstChild == null)?"":nn.FirstChild.InnerText) : ((v < 0) ? "" : sharedString[v]));
                };
                if (colums.Count !=0)   data.Add(colums.ToArray());  /*ИМПОРТ ТУТ*/
        };            
        return data;
       }
```

Для ускорения (более 10 000 записей) рекомендую переписать, что б вместо data.Add (в двух местах) данные отправлялись в СУБД напрямую (`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` вовнуть цикла). Для обьемов более 2Gb  XmlDocument лучше заменить на XmlReader но это не очень то просто.

Файл xlsx состоит из zip-обвёртки, но она отличается от zip тем, что метки длинны "файлов" уже проставлены. По умолчанию xlsx упакованы deflate. По другому упакованых покачто не встречал. Дальше вам нужен "словарь" *sharedStrings.xml*. А после словаря можно читать данные *sheet1.xml*.