# C# ошибка при работе с EXCEL

Tags: c#, excel

Необходимо считать некоторые столбцы из документа excel для дальнейшей с ним работы. Написал код:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;



public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opfd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (opfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            textBox1.Text = opfd.FileName;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  string ConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO\"; Data Source={0}", filename);
        //Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;extended properties=\"excel 8.0
        string stringconn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(stringconn);
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + textBox2.Text + "$]", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка");
    }
}
```

При первой загрузке документа всё ок, но дальше при попытке загрузки того же файла возникает ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException" в
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Непредвиденная ошибка драйвера внешней базы
>   данных (1).

А при попытке загрузить файл другого формата (например, .xlsx) возникает вот такая ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException" в
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Внешняя таблица не имеет предполагаемый
>   формат.

Подскажите, как поправить код для корректной работы программы.

Comment: 8-мая версия excel - xls. Попробуйте не задавать версию, или пробуйте другую версию задать (выше 8). 12-тая скорее всего http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_Windows

Comment: Стуктура xlsx не сложная (в отличие от xls), вот пример как импортировать без доп-библиотек. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600965/17974

Comment: Пробовал прописывать 12-ую, возникала ошибка Дополнительные сведения: Невозможно найти устанавливаемый ISAM.

Comment: Там версия в 2-х местах. Возможно глянуть в сети строку подключения нужно.

Comment: Cпасибо, уже разбираюсь. Дополнительные сведения: Поставщик "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" не зарегистрирован на локальном компьютере. Не подскажите, это нужно подключать новую библиотеку?

Comment: Разобрался в первом вопросе. Нужно было поставить драйвер: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734