# Как вытащить данные из определенной ячейки excel нескольких файлов

Tags: excel

Есть множество файлов excel ( более 10000 ), открывать каждый файл и копировать от туда информацию - уйдет уйма времени.

Вопрос - каким образом можно вытянуть текст, например из первого листа ячейки K6 сразу из нескольких листов, и записать эти данные, хоть куда-нибудь, хотя бы в txt файл.

Comment: Взять, например, vb, или python и написать прогу строк на 10

Comment: @AlexanderChernin а какими то базовыми методами?

Comment: Мне кажется, что только если VisualBasic

Comment: Но если множество именно файлов с листами, то лучше python

Comment: Можно и в VBA. Да, файлы будут открываться, но пользователь этого может не видеть. Уточните задачу, язык

Comment: Смотря какой excel. xls парсится в один проход без проблем, если продумать обход SAT. xlsx нужно разпаковывать ZIP, поэтому займет дольше времени, но можно выиграть время, что б разпаковывать не всё подрят, а только нужные куски (лист, и словарь, словарь можно частично). Если тема интересна - дам ссылки. Питон - не силен. с++/с#

Comment: @nick_n_a интересно) покажите линк пожалуйста

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/897691/17974 вижу вопрос закрыли... надо будет где-то ещё сборную солянку оставить. Для xlsx дополнительно нужно найти библиотеки, расжимающие zip.

Answer (score 1):

Данная документация позволила мне сделать набор утилит как для парсинга, так и для генерации xls/xlsx. Скажу так, что xls состоит из обвёртки и данных. Xlsx из "почти" zip архива (т.е. немного отличается от обычного zip) и набора xml (сам документ + словарь + некоторые другие данные). Нужно чётко понимать что парсится, потому что иногда под excel могут подразумевать xml и html документы, которые msoffice умеет конвертировать в документ.

- фомат xls сигнатура `D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1` либо `09 08` для соовсем старых версий.
- Документация обвёртки xls  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942138.aspx
- Документация обвёртки xls http://www.amwa.tv/downloads/specifications/aafcontainerspec-v1.0.1.pdf
- Документация данных xls https://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf

Алгоритм примерно такой:
  1. Считать MSAT c заголовка. Либо прочесть всю цепочку SAT, либо читать её "по мере поступления".
  2. Прочесть (с учётом MSAT+SAT+SSAT) "корень" документа, его легко найти по сигнатуре `09 08` с адресом кратным 512. В корне документа прочесть словарь, и адреса листов (сигнатура `85 00`).
  3. Читать документ вхолостую пока не пойдут данные листа. Лист всегда начинается с сигнатуры `09 08`.
  4. Читаем лист, данные листа связываем со словарём (если нужно).

Если документ меньше 66 кбайт, то данные практически не фрагментированы, и файл очень легко парсится. Рекомендую парсить маленький файл, потом до 6Мб, потом свыше 10Мб. Т.к. там особенности с MSAT.

Для xlsx ccылки

- От микрософта MS-XLSX http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181.aspx
- ECMA http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm
- http://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats
- http://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Office_Open_XML
- SO-en http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886027/looking-for-a-clear-description-of-excels-xlsx-xml-format
- Парсинг xlsx на с# http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600965/17974
- php экспорт хабр http://habr.com/post/236107

  Для упрощения если не нашли хорошую библиотеку для xlsx (не всегда библиотеки удобны и всё парсят) рекомендую две вещи: a) zip-депаковцик  б) xml-библиотеку. Внутри архива есть листы, например `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml` и есть "словарь" `xl/sharedStrings.xml`- в котором храняться все строковые данные.

Алгоритм такой 
   1. открыть файл, найти лист, найти словарь. 
   2. Считать словарь, распаковать словарь.
   3. Считать лист, распаковать, данные листа связать с словарём. Без словаря записываются только числовые данные.

В вашем случае -  лист - не обязательно распаковывать до конца. Достаточно найти нужные данные и остановить декомпрессию. В данных будет ссылка на словарь - то же, считать словарь до елемента с вашим номером.

P.S. Библиотеки как правило не заточены на "узкие" задачи. Данные ячейки будут записаны не всегда в одном и том же месте файла в 99,99% случаев. Мое мнение - чтение значения одной ячейки через библиотеку займет больше процессорного времени и ресурсов ПК (т.к. как правило библиотека парсит весь документ) чем если написать узкоспециализированый парсер.